# how to make 2 functions follow each other only if one finished doing its work

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

ok so i have 2 functions, they both get a global variable and they both are threads,

```
function 1
get global variable
do something
sleep()

function 2
get global variable
do something
sleep()
```

right now they are running in sync(same timestamp for both of them) or locking(func1 goes to sleep and only after it wakes up then func2 starts) depending on the code i use
what i want to happen is func1 doing its work and going to sleep and only then func2 start running and going to sleep, also i need a way to make sure they don't try to overrun each other if they wake up in the same time.

how can i achieve such a behavior?

Comment: Why not set the last line of func1 to call func2?

Comment: cause the func1 goes to sleep it wont run thread2 untill it wakes up

Comment: + it just adds so much more complexity to the code.. making it almost spaghetti code in my case cause the user is choosing either he want's to run func1 or func2 or to run them together...

Comment: used the the threads lock mechanism instead of queue, the post above you gave me this link [link] https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732 [/link] and i used the article to fix it using locks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is for each functions to behave like a "critical section". A critical section of code is one that can only be executed by one thread at a time. A simple way-old school approach of doing this is to use Peterson's algorithm for critical sections. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/petersons-algorithm-using-processes-shared-memory/) 
For a better approach you can synchronize threads using **locks**. This does not allow the thread to enter another function if the lock is not released by the first function. [Here](https://hackernoon.com/synchronization-primitives-in-python-564f89fee732) is a nice place to read about it.

Comment: i tried using locks the problem is the variable they both share and the data comes from the web browser, that means that even if they execute one after the other they do it so fast that when func2 goes to get the data to work with, its not on the screen yet because the page didn't load fast enough.. and then it throw's an error it couldnt find the data even tho when i look i can see the elemnt it was looking for after the page loaded...

Comment: Sorry for the generic solution. I can't think of any other way to do it other than using a sleep() at the start of your critical section of function2 , thereby forcing a wait.

Comment: i wish it was that simple sometimes the sleep of func1 and func2 overlap so they wake up in the same time, its not a constant sleep it always changes within some range so even if i put a 5 seconds sleep on func2 start sometimes the func1 will wake up when the func2 will wake up causing an error..